# Element event listener affects other element

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I'm adding divs on user clicks.
If the user clicks an exciting div I want it to change color.
Yet somehow the affected div is always the last appended one. How can I make the pressed div be the one who is affected?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e =>{
    el=document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(el)
    el.style.left = e.clientX-25 + 'px'
    el.style.top = e.clientY-25 + 'px'
    el.addEventListener('click', e =>{
      el.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    })
})
```

```css
div {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        click to make two different squres. then click again on the first squre you created.
    </body>
</html>
```

try running this code, click to create two squres, then click again on your first squre. Why whould the second one change color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are implicitly creating a global variable named `el` here:

```
el=document.createElement('div')
```

When you click on a square, the click listener will run and do:

```
el.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
```

This will look up what `el` currently references and change its style. But `el` is global, and it gets reassigned every time a click occurs (and a square is created). So, any time you click *any* of the squares, the *last* square created will always be the one that gets its style changed.

Declare the `el` so that it's only scoped to the function, rather than global.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const el = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(el)
  el.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px'
  el.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px'
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  click to make two different squres. then click again on the first squre you created.
</body>

</html>
```

I'd highly recommend using ESLint and its [no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) rule to help yourself avoid making these sorts of mistakes.

You also might want to not create a square if you're clicking on an existing square - instead, only change the existing square's color. If that's what you want, then keep the event from propagating.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const el = document.createElement('div')
  document.body.appendChild(el)
  el.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px'
  el.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px'
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // don't let the event bubble up to the click listener above
    e.stopPropagation();
    el.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
  })
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  click to make two different squres. then click again on the first squre you created.
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I didn't figure out it creates a global var. And you completely read my mind about the propagation. Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanna ask what happens when div clicked and event bubbled up in the second scenerio?

Comment: @UPinar While the event is bubbling, listeners attached to inner elements run before listeners attached to outer elements. `e.stopPropagation()` stops the event from propagating (upward, here), which results in other listeners attached to ancestors from running.

Comment: the thing that i dont understand well is, when you create a div and assign it to `el` and second time you click that same div, bubbling up not happens and dont create another div is okay for me but when you clicked different places and create 2 divs then when you click the first one and bublling not happens is the thing that i dont understand are divs `el`s are making array or acting like that ?

Comment: @UPinar The `el`s don't really exist as a collection anywhere, but each one has a reference to itself in its click listener. Add one square, and you get a square element and a square listener on the heap. Add another square, and the same thing happens. Each batch is independent.

Comment: So one last question. When clicking the same div again, is it directly find that `el` in heap and fire that `el:click` event first or it fire document.click event (because we clicked document) and because of there is an `el:click` event inside (we created that `el` before),  `document.click` it dont fires document and fire `el:click` and do not bubble up